# Difference between let and def

Tags: ruby, rspec

I wonder between method and let definition inside rspec describe block? Why should I use let instead def?

```
let(:create_user) { post :create }
```

Vs

```
def create_user
  post :create
end
```

Both ways seems to work the same inside the test:

```
expect { create_user }.to change { User.count }.by(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you will use the `let` definition for some kind of values you are testing(for example `let(:apple) { 2 + 3 }`). Another important thing about `let` is that it uses memoization. That means once you called the name for the let clause the result is cached and not calculated any more( `apple` becomes 5 and `2 + 3` is never calculated again).

You would normally use `def` to define methods. In specs is common to use methods to share common logic between tests, like a complex setup for the spec.

`let` has another useful property - you can use its synonym `subject` which can help you to shorten your [specs](http://betterspecs.org/#subject).

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it is the only difference, but `let` memoizes it's value. So it would be closer to:

```
def create_user
  @_create_user ||= post :create
end
```

Comment: Great. Value is memoized inside "it" block level and not on "describe" block.

Answer (score 1):

Another important difference is that you can pass a parameter to a method, but not to a `let`.